# How to import more than 100 products in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, csv, limit

I am using Magento import function from admin panel and I am trying to import CSV files. The validation is passed, import process is success but when I look to catalog then I see that 100 products have the attribute set id and the rest do not have the attribute set id.

I've try to put the same product information 140 times in a CSV file, with different SKU. It is importing 100 and then is not doing it anymore. The products are created in admin but without an attribute set id and this is not good.

Did someone had the same problem? How to fix it?

Comment: I'm sure you won't have fallen for this, but better safe than sorry so to speak. You aren't limiting your page view to 100 items and there's a second page with the remaining items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Magento standard import functionality is not very reliable. You can try the following:

- import in **batches** of 100 products
- get an **import/export extension**. There are a lot to choose from.

Personally I always use an extension for import of more then 100 products.

Comment: Hello, Can you please give me an example for an extension that is reliable?

Comment: Sure. Try this one: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-export-products-extension-for-simple-products-configurable-products-bundle-products-group-products-downloadable-products.html

Comment: One of the best extensions to use to import products : Mamgi. Its totally free : http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/

Comment: Free extensons are good until you need support from their developer :)

Comment: @andy1786  I have downloaded it from above source but unable to integrate it in my magento. It has so many folders and those folders are not present in magento.How can i integrate magmi to my magento?

Comment: You have to upload magni folder to magento root, then go to example.com/magmi/web/magmi.php, put user and pass : magni. After that you have to setup the dB connection and then you will login with magento login.